# cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'char'

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Changed completely due to suggestions from other member. Most problems solved, still having problems. Now won't output any names from the array in main. Not sure if I'm passing them back correctly from function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void bubblesort(string[], const int);
int sub = 0;

int main()
{
const int maxsize = 100;
string friendArray[maxsize];

ifstream friends;
friends.open("myFriends.dat");

while (sub < maxsize)
 {
  getline(friends, friendArray[sub]);
  sub++;
 }

 bubblesort(friendArray, maxsize);


 cout<<friendArray[0]<<" "<<friendArray[1]<<" "<<friendArray[2];

 system("pause");
 return 0;
}



void bubblesort(string *array, const int size)
{
    bool swap;
    string temp;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for (int count = 1; count < (size - 1); count++)
        {
            if(array[count-1] >array[count])
            {
                temp = array[count-1];
                array[count-1] = array[count];
                array[count] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while(swap);

}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem isn't necessarily that `temp` inside `bubblesort` is not a `char`, the problem is that `array` is declared as a `string` and not a `string[]`.

The reason you're getting the error is because `array[count+1]` is of type `char`, and `temp` is of type `string`. `std::swap` expects two elements of the same type.

However, that may be the least of your problems, your code doesn't compile for quite a few reasons. Not just that but you're passing in `maxsize` to `bubblesort` at each iteration. There's a flaw in both your logic and your syntax.

**EDIT:** Since you're still having trouble getting the sorting to work, here's a working modification of your code:

```
#include <iostream>

void bubblesort(std::string array[], size_t size)
{
  bool bSwapped;
  std::string temp;

   do
   {
      bSwapped = false;
      for (size_t count = 1; count < size; count++)
      {
         if(array[count-1] > array[count])
         {
            std::swap(array[count-1], array[count]);
            bSwapped = true;
         }
      }
   }
   while(bSwapped);
}

int main(void)
{
   std::string array[] = { "def", "ghk", "abc", "world", "hello" };

   bubblesort(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array));

   for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array); ++i)
      std::cout << array[i] + " ";

   std::cout << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

`bubblesort` could also be written as: `void bubblesort(std::string *array, size_t size)`. There's no difference in this case since, when passed to a function, arrays decay into pointers.

Since arrays are passed by reference, a pointer to the first element, any modifications made to `array` inside of `bubblesort` will actually be modifying your array in `main`. So that's how arrays are "returned".

`std::vector` is a good alternative to the standard array, since it automatically resizes and obviously contains the length of the internal array so that you don't have to pass the size everywhere you pass an `std::vector`. You can also use it the same way as a regular array.

Comment: Yes I've come to realize, now I have access violations

Comment: @sircrisp time to pull out the debugger. Hint: a bubble sort `for` loop would usually look like: `count = 1; count < size; count++`, and you'll be swapping `[count-1] and [count]`. Otherwise, you'll go passed the end of your array when `count = size-1`, and you do `array[count+1]`.

Comment: I just don't seem to be getting this at all I'm having a very hard time on this sorting/searching... Is there an example I can look at of strings being sorted?

Comment: @sircrisp: Have you checked the pseudocode at the [bubblesort Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)?

Comment: It helped me tweak the code a tad but how do I return the sorted array?

Comment: @sircrisp: I'll update my answer with a working modification of your code.

Comment: Thank you, I have my sorting working properly now but I'm having a problem returning the array. At the bottom of the function I have return *array; and that works but how do I access it in main?

Comment: @sircrisp: Read the couple of lines I just added. Arrays are passed by reference, therefore making any changes to the array in `bubblesort` is actually making the changes to the array in `main`. There's no need for an explicit `return`. Run the program above and you'll see.

Comment: You have made this a lot easier for me to understand and I would not have known variables are passed by reference ! Thank you!!!

Comment: @sircrisp: Not all variables are passed by reference; if you pass a pointer to a variable it'll be passed by reference. The name of an array is the address of it's first element, which turns into a pointer when passed to a function. `size_t size` is **not** passed by reference, it's not a pointer or a "reference" that uses the `&` operator.

Comment: I only have one more question, in your code why is array passed to bubblesort 3 times? (array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array). I haven't heard about pointers till you guys mentioned them so you might be knocking me back off track.

Comment: @sircrisp: That's a way of getting the length of an array. You divide the total size of the array by the size of the first element, which will give you the number of elements in an array. `sizeof` is calculated at compile time. The compiler will turn that into ` bubblesort(array, 5);`, since `array` has 5 elements.

Comment: I feel like I'm being a huge waste of time but care to look at my latest edit ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5600/discussion-between-sircrisp-and-auscbloke)

Comment: @sircrisp: Your code above is outputting what you're telling it to. You're telling it there are 100 elements, and `std::string`s are initialized to `""`. Therefore unless you filled `98+ elements, elements 0-2 are `""`. Do `bubblesort(friendArray, sub)`.

Answer (score 4):

temp is a string, `array[count]` is a char (since an std::string is a vector of char elements.) I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but the compiler is correct - you can't assign a char to a string.

You could change `temp` to be a char, since all you do with it is assign a char to it, and then assign it back to an element of array, which is also a char.

Comment: Main reads in names from a file into an array. The function is supposed to sort the names. That's what I am trying to do.

Comment: When you index into a `string` you are getting/setting a `char`, not a `string`.  You should pass a `vector<string>&` to your function, not a `string` (that is unfortunately named `array`).

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you think it should do. The bubblesort() function sorts the characters in a single string alphabetically, for one thing.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare `temp` as `char`. You can use [`std::swap`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/swap.html) to avoid such mistakes in the future:

```
std::swap(array[count], array[count+1]);
```

This would make your code compile, but it would not do what you're trying to do (bubblesort). The problem is that you are passing a single string (which is also an "array" of characters) instead of an array of strings, which is, in a very lose sense, "an array of arrays of characters". Your bubblesort needs to accept `string *array` as its first parameter.

Comment: I haven't yet discovered how to use std:: so I'm not sure what that code would do. The sort function is supposed to sort the names read in to the array passed from main. That's what I am trying to do.

Comment: If array[count] is a char. Where did the names in arrays elements go?

Comment: @sircrisp yet you are using `std` quite successfully: `string` is a shorthand for `std::string` :-) Don't get discouraged, your code is close to working.

Comment: @sircrisp I updated the answer to explain where did the rest of the elements go (short answer: you did not pass them to bubblesort).

Comment: I am very appreciative for the advice but I still don't seem to be getting it...  What difference does adding * to the beginning of array make? When I was taught about passing parameters to functions it was only with integers so I'm trying to learn out of a book but it doesn't have any examples with arrays and strings either.

Comment: @sircrisp it makes it a pointer, which is an equivalent of arrays in C/C++ land. The other syntax is `string array[]`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Arrays and pointers are **not** the same in C land. Arrays can decay to pointers when passed to functions, but they're still a different beast.

Comment: Ah that helped adding [] behind it but the pointer did not. I got confused since you don't add it while passing to the function. Now I'm getting a access violation when it tries to read the first name though -.-

Comment: @AusCBloke I understand the differences. Yet considering the code we're tying to correct, I think the explanation of distinctions between arrays and pointers would be a bit premature. I am sure sircrisp will learn it at some future time. At this point, however, adding an asterisk would simply let him continue coding, while mentioning the pointers would encourage some reading when the assignment is complete :)